# a way to avoid to rename the file to open when using document function (XSLT)?

Tags: xslt, document, filenames, concatenation

I made an xslt file to correct an xml file (`File1.xml`) with another one (`File1CORR.xml`).
The problem is that I have 50 xml files to correct and that I have to rename the document to open in the XSLT file 50 times. As you can see the files naming is quite similar. So, I wonder if there is not a way to avoid to rename by using some trick, so that, for instance :

```
<xsl:if test="not($myKey1=document('fichier1CORR.xml')/Context/descriptor/deleteBB/.|document('fichier1CORR.xml')/Context/descriptor/replaceBB/.)">
```

would be replaced to refer to the input file & CORR & .xml using maybe the concat function?

Comment: <xsl:if test="not($myKey1=document('fichier1CORR.xml')/Context/descriptor/deleteBB/.|document('fichier1CORR.xml')/Context/descriptor/replaceBB/.)">

Comment: I tried, but I can't figure out how, I put a excerpt in my (the first) comment

Answer (score 2):

Pass the path to the file to be corrected as an external (global) parameter to the transformation:

```
<xsl:param name="pFilePath"/>

<xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="document($pFilePath)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc/node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 2.0 allows all XML documents corrections to be performed in a single transformation**. All filepaths can be read from a separate XML document and the same corrections can be done to all specified documents. The **[`<xsl:result-document>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-result-document)** instruction will be used to save every corrected XML document and continue the transformation with corrections to the remaining not processed documents.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer, but unfortunately the corrections contained in my correction files are different each time..., in fact I have 50 FilesCORR.xml... But maybe I don't get it, grasp the idea... In any case, thanks again for your answer :)

Comment: @user1240544 You should give it a try; keeping the list of file names in a separate Xml document like Dimitre suggests would make things even simpler than my solution. In any case passing the whole file name as a param is simpler than concat'ing it (like I did suggest).

Comment: @user1240544: I know that the corrections are different in time -- why do you think this solution supposes they aren't? No such assumption is made.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a input param for your xslt and use it in a variable:

```
<!-- declare param with default value 1 -->
<xsl:param name="foo" select="1"/>

<!-- concat param $foo to constant file name parts -->
<xsl:variable name="currentCORRFile" select="concat('fichier', $foo, 'CORR.xml')" />

<!-- use current file name -->
<xsl:template match="baz">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($currentCORRFile)/Context/descriptor/deleteBB/." />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks again Filburt, I will give it a try, but it seems to be what I looked for :)